# UE4 opens C++ project the second time

Tags: unreal-4, unreal

When I create new C++ Project (Base Code), UE4 opens only code editor (MS VSCode). Then when I close code editor and I open this project, UE4 opens its editor. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When set as a C++ project UE is set to assume you want to code. So it opens visual studio. Seems reasonable.

See this : https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/319140/how-to-deactivate-visual-studio-launching-3.html

You can disable it by setting it in the ini file:

`[/Script/SourceCodeAccess.SourceCodeAccessSettings]
 PreferredAccessor=NullSourceCodeAccessor`